# to use changed value in setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
    //to make an ajax call to server to get to get the list data
    function makeAjaxCall()
    {
        loginSuccess =0;

        //to make an ajax call to server to get the supported banks details
        var xmlhttp;

        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            alert('here'+xmlhttp.readyState+'stat='+xmlhttp.status)
            if( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 )
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
                if(xmlhttp.responseText != '' )
                {
                    loginSuccess =1;
                    renderResponse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
                //else
                {

                }
            }
            //else if(  )
        }


        var params = "flagLogin="+flagLogin+"&listName="+selectedList+formData+loginPara;

        //var url = serverURL;
        var url = 'https://blah.com';

        //alert('param='+params)
        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(params);

        setTimeout('showLoginAgain()',15000);

        // return
        return;
    }
```

In the above code , I am making ajax calls and I want to use the value of global variable `loginSuccess` when `showLoginAgain()` gets called - 15 seconds after `setTimeout()` gets called.

How to make the second ajax call change the value of the variable by the time `showLoginAgain()` for first ajax call is invoked?

Comment: You can call `setTimeout(showLoginAgain,15000);` to make the code a bit more effective.

Comment: What if you passed the value as a function parameter instead of using a global?

Comment: I have edited your question, but I am not sure if I take it right: by `showLoginAgain` you mean `makeAjaxCall`? Please re-edit the question to clarify.

Comment: showLoginAgain() is another function which gets called 15 sec after setTimeout() is called.